# Why can't Django detect a static file outside of my project folder in local?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

In a Django template tag, I am returning a file path that is outside of my project folder. I am placing this in my template. My files look like this:

```
myproject (contains project, app, manage.py, etc)
myfolder
|
+----styles.css
```

In my template tag, this is what I am returning:

```
from myproject.settings import BASE_DIR
from pathlib import Path

...

def get_outside_file():
    HOME_DIR = Path(BASE_DIR).parent
    return os.path.join(HOME_DIR, 'myfolder/styles.css')
```

Unfortunately, in my template, I get this error:

```
"GET /Users/myusername/myfolder/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404
```

I clearly have the file in that folder, but Django can't seem to detect it. How can I fix this issue? Thanks for any help.

BTW, I am on Mac OsX, if that helps.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using this approach in stead of setting the `STATIC_URL` or the `STATIC_ROOT` values in settings.py?

Comment: Yes, I know this is not ideal, but I can't change the location of that one file in local.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your Path to `STATICFILES_DIRS`in settings.py like

```
HOME_DIR = Path(BASE_DIR).parent

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
os.path.join(HOME_DIR, 'myfolder/styles.css')]
```

Comment: Could you expand on this? How would you use the directory in the template tag?

Comment: add a STATIC_ROOT in your Settings.py like 
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
 and then do a manage.py collectstatic command.
 all your static files will be now stored in a folder called static in you project base dir . 
 from there you can access your files like you do usually using the static tag